# Getting section size with nasm -f bin

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

I'm trying to compile this with `nasm -f bin -o bo.bin bo.nasm`:

```
bits 16
cpu 8086
org 0  ; Default.

section HEADER align=1
section _TEXT follows=HEADER align=1
section CONST follows=_TEXT align=1
section CONST2 follows=CONST align=1
section _DATA follows=CONST2 align=1
section _BSS follows=_DATA nobits align=1

section HEADER
mov si, section._TEXT.start
mov di, section.CONST.start
db 0xb9  ; mov cx, ...
; bo.nasm:17: error: operand 1: expression is not simple or relocatable
dw section.CONST.start-section._TEXT.start

section _TEXT 

; --- End of header.

section _TEXT
db 'FOO/'

section _DATA
db 'BARR/'

section _TEXT
db 'FOOD/'

section _BSS   
v1: resb 0x1000
v2: resb 2
```

I'm getting this error for the `dw` line:

```
bo.nasm:17: error: operand 1: expression is not simple or relocatable
```

In the `dw` line I want to emit the byte size of the _TEXT section. `section.CONST.start-section._TEXT.start` is an implementation detail, it can be changed. (I also tried with the `.vstart` suffix instead of `.start`, but it didn't help. I looked at the source code of nasm, and I couldn't find any other lables it defines.)

I need a solution which:

- compiles successfully with `nasm -f bin`. Other assemblers and other output formats are not allowed.
- doesn't modify anything below the `; --- End of header.` line, e.g. adding a label after `db 'FOOD/'` is not allowed. (This is because I'm writing a nasm %include library, and asking the user to add labels would make it error-prone.)
- doesn't increase the file size, e.g. computing the value with `mov cx, di` + `sub cx, si` is not allowed, I need the result in the existing `dw`. (This is because I will repace the HEADER contents with the actual file format header, which doesn't contain assembly instructions.)

Comment: I use `align 16` + `section_end` or `section_size` style [labels after the data to emit](https://hg.ulukai.org/ecm/ldebug/file/c34f60ea5916/source/debug.asm#l8122), then [sum all the respective deltas](https://hg.ulukai.org/ecm/ldebug/file/c34f60ea5916/source/debug.asm#l8242). Eg `text_end - text_start` to figure out the length of the "text" section. NASM allows some arithmetic on addresses like this, but none that crosses sections. So you need to list all sections separately, and put a label behind the end of the data. (NASM 2.10 was supposed to introduce `%final` but that was scrapped.)

Comment: @ecm: Thank you for the insights. I already knew about the solution with labels at the end of the sections (search for *adding a label* in the question), I was hoping to get a solution without them. Nevertheless, if the user forgets to call the macro which defines those labels, then NASM will fail with lots of undefined symbol errors, and thus they will notice.

Comment: Yes, that's one reason I didn't post this as an answer, as it doesn't resolve all your requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like what I want is not possible with NASM, because NASM can't do arithmetic using labels from multiple sections. As a workaround, after adding the label `text.end` to the end of the `_TEXT` section, this works:

```
dw TEXT.end-section.TEXT.start
```